# Adding metadata with images to audio files using ffmpeg

Tags: python, linux, bash, audio, ffmpeg

**UPDATE** : 
Not able to embed artwork to audio file , here my command:
`ffmpeg -i ./tmp/Feeling_Good.mp3 -i './tmp/artwork/default.png' -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -codec -id3v2_version 3 -metadata title='Feeling Good' -metadata TPE1='Gryffin' -metadata TPE2='Gryffin' -metadata album='' -metadata genre=' ' ./tmp/fumen_Feeling_Good.mp3`

**ERROR** : `[NULL @ 0x106b0e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '3'
3: Invalid argument`

I want to add album art and meta data at one go to audio files , I have tried this command , but it doesn't seem to work moreover it creates an empty file.
Here's my command :

`ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i ./tmp/Heres_to_never_growing_up.mp3 -i ./tmp/artwork/default.png -codec copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata title='Heres to never growing up' -metadata TPE1='Avril Lavigne' -metadata TPE2='Avril Lavigne' -metadata comment='Cover (Front)' -metadata album='unnamed' -metadata genre='unnamed' ./tmp/Heres_to_never_growing_up.mp3`

Comment: FFmpeg cannot edit files in-place. Output file has to be different than input file.

Comment: Ok ,but are the other parameters correct ?

Comment: The empty file problem is fixed for now  , but I am not able to add the artwork.
PS. Updated the Question

Comment: That's odd, Your updated command line looks correct to me. Perhaps verify your version of ffmpeg. Another idea would be to skip the `-id3v2_version` unless you must use v2.3. ffmpeg will default to id3 v2.4. 

Source: [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-AVOptions)

"... to write an ID3v2.3 header instead of a default ID3v2.4 to an MP3 file...."